# Using insert and update on the 'when matched then' // merge

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to use an INSERT AND an UPDATE on the `When matched then` ?  ? I saw on the web that it's note possible so my question is : how can i do something like below ?

```
create table target_table(a, b, c, d, e) as (
   select 1, 2, 'NO',  100,'MDE' from dual union all
   select 1, 3, 'NO',  100,'AGC' from dual union all
   select 1, 4, 'NO',  100,'MDE' from dual union all
   select 1, 6, 'YES',  100,'MDE' from dual union all
   select 1, 5, 'NO',  100,'MDE' from dual );


create table source_table(a, b, c, d, e) as (
   select 1, 0, 'NO',  200,'AGC'  from dual union all
   select 1, 1, 'NO',  200,'MDE'  from dual union all
   select 1, 3, 'YES', 200,'AGC'  from dual union all
   select 1, 4, 'NO',  200,'MDE'  from dual union all
   select 1, 5, 'YES', 200,'MDE'  from dual );


merge into target_table t
using source_table s
on (t.a = s.a and t.b = s.b)
when matched then 
case 
      when t.c = 'NO' and s.c = 'YES' and t.e = 'MDE' and s.e = 'MDE' then update set t.d = s.d, t.c = s.c
      when t.e <> 'MDE' and s.e <> 'MDE' then insert values (s.a, s.b, s.c, s.d, s.e)
end 
when not matched then insert values (s.a, s.b, s.c, s.d, s.e);
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is a GUI that allows you to connect to databases. It's not a database in and of itself. What rdbms platform is the database you're connecting to? (Oracle? SQL Server? Something else?)

Comment: Also, please edit your question to include the expected output of your target_table.

Comment: @Boneist it is connect to Oracle. Okey, i'll edit my question

Answer (score 2):

Let's sort things out. 
First https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F

- matched     -> update/delete
- not matched -> insert

No mixing allowed.

So you want to insert when t.e and s.e are != 'MDE' or (t.a = s.a and t.b = s.b)
And the update only when  t.c = 'NO' and s.c = 'YES' and t.e = 'MDE' and s.e = 'MDE'

So did you try:

```
merge into target_table t
using source_table s
on (t.a = s.a and t.b = s.b and not ( t.e <> 'MDE' and s.e <> 'MDE'))
when matched then 
    update set t.d = s.d, t.c = s.c 
    where t.c = 'NO' and s.c = 'YES' and t.e = 'MDE' and s.e = 'MDE' 
when not matched then insert values (s.a, s.b, s.c, s.d, s.e)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for you answer ! So it's work but i don't really understand how ... the "and not ( t.e <> 'MDE' and s.e <> 'MDE' )" is the same that "and t.e = 'MDE' and s.e = 'MDE'" ?

Comment: The part `and not (t.e <> 'MDE' and s.e <> 'MDE')` is to get into your insert case which you wanted to reach with the case statement.  Line 7 in your merge statement

Comment: Okey, but `and (t.e = 'MDE' and s.e = 'MDE')` is the same no ? instead of `and not (t.e <> 'MDE' and s.e <> 'MDE')`

Comment: That is up to you .. I only transfered your logic so it is doing the stuff you mentioned. If it's possible to write it dense feel free to do so.